# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined Google maps API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

can anyone please tell me why this error is coming in google places API code

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')
ur.onPlaceChanged
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:82:49

```
 79 | const onLoad = autoC => setAutocomplete(autoC);
  80 | 
  81 | const onPlaceChanged = () => {
> 82 |   const lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
     |                                               ^  83 |   const lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
  84 |   setCoords({
  85 |     lat,[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Have you checked the plain `json` as to whether the `geometry` key exists or not?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue.